# Can robots surpass humans?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Is it possible that sometime in the near future, that intelligent life will be able to eclipse human life? And if it is possible, will these consequences be catastrophic?

Comment: Are you saying that humans are not "intelligent life?" And what exactly do you mean by "eclipse?" There are whole bookshelves of turgid speculation on this topic, both fiction and non-fiction, so the question as written seems a bit too broad for Worldbuilding's Q&A format.

Comment: "intellegent life" is humans, but man made items are the definition

Comment: That was a polite prod for you to edit the question to clarify. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: Hi Deez Nuts, welcome to Worldbuilding! Of course this is _possible_. Or do you actually want to ask if "Terminator" or "Matrix" scenarios are _likely_?

Comment: children are man/woman-made and they eclipse their parents every hundred years or so.  I'm not thrilled with eventually having to hand over the reins to the next generation, but I wouldn't call it a catastrophe.  Robots are just children with thicker skin.

Comment: Hello, *Deez Nuts*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  This question is extremely opinion based.  Perhaps you could edit the question to include constraints for answers, and a method for deciding which answers are better than others.  Please take our [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about the site.  Have a nice day!

Comment: ## We don't know, but researchers are working on it. ## While your question is a little vague, I'm going to take it as "Is it possible for an artificial intelligence to be superior to humans in every way?". As @Carlos Zamora said in their answer, there are certainly already artificial intelligences that are better than humans in certain ways. For instance, it's been a long time since the top humans were able to beat the top computers in chess, and Go is currently being revolutionized in the same way. Perhaps we should ask for versatility, as a chess-playing AI currently is unable to play Go at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deez: If your question is "will intelligent robots be able to damage humans?" The answer is: "They already are". There are missiles with artificial intelligence whose sole purpose is to find and kill (and I think that could be cataloged as "catastrophic"). Any modern auto-guided weapon has some degree of intelligence devoted solely to damage, destroy and kill.

However, the "decision" of "what" and "when" to destroy is still managed by a human. Perhaps the real menace will arrive when the machines decide by themselves what and when to destroy.

Will it happen sometime? It depends: We humans make the programming. If we program a machine to take those decisions on their own and based on their own evaluation, then surely they will. And (as it has been historically proven by the endless patching of all the software we use), we humans are not perfect developers and our code always contains some degree of "opportunity areas" and needs to be "upgraded" sometimes. If we humans develop a highly intelligent entity AND we put it in charge of any weapon of mass destruction, then surely the results will be catastrophic.